# Why does XDebug remote debugging loses my path mapping (Eclipse) after submit?

Tags: xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I am using XDebug to remote debug an application in Eclipse. I have probably not correctly configured Eclipse.
When I start debugging everything works fine. But as soon as I submit a form, the debugger continues working but Eclipse does not seem to be able to map the server side files to my local files.

Here is the stack trace I see before the submit:

```
wwwc.example.com [PHP Web Application]  
  PHP Application   
    Remote Launch (suspended)   
      www.example.com/htdocs/toto.inc.php.toto_inc : lineno 12() www.example.com/htdocs/toto.inc.php at line 12 
      www.example.com/htdocs/toto.inc.php.include : lineno 23() www.example.com/htdocs/toto.inc.php at line 23  
      www.example.com/htdocs/simple.inc.php.include_once : lineno 325() www.example.com/htdocs/simple.inc.php at line 325   
      www.example.com/htdocs/index.php.{main} : lineno 106() www.example.com/htdocs/index.php at line 106
```

After submit

```
wwc.example.com [PHP Web Application]   
  PHP Application   
    Remote Launch (stepping)    
      /stuff/share/websites/wwwc.example.com/process.php.{main} : lineno 8() /stuff/share/websites/wwwc.example.com/process.php at line 8
```

Notice that the path after submit (/struff/share/website/wwwc.example.com) is server side while the path before (www.example.com/htdocs) is on my computer. The file and line numbers are correct.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The disk on the server was mounted on a NTFS file system.

There was case error on the action URL (which was not discovererd because NTFS is case insensitive).

Eclipse's mapping strategy is case sensitive which means it did not map the local file to the remote file.

Fixing the case error solved the mapping problem.

Comment: This answer solved the issue for me. I had used a large X: when mapping my samba share. Changing it to a small x: got me passed the next hurdle.